# How to initialize a member variable in a constructor with CodeDOM?

Tags: codedom

I hope can help me, the problem is this, 
I want to initialize a member variable in the constructor of a class with CodeDOM to achieve something like this:

```
Public Sub New()

    MyBase.New

    Me._myOfficeApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

End Sub
```

The code I use to do that is:

```
' Create a Public Class Constructor
Dim aConstructor As New CodeConstructor()
aConstructor.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public
Dim ca As New CodeAssignStatement()
ca.Left = New CodeFieldReferenceExpression(New CodeThisReferenceExpression(), "_myOfficeApp")

ca.Right = New CodeTypeReferenceExpression("New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application")

aConstructor.Statements.Add(ca)
```

My question is that I do not think I'm doing it the right way, maybe you could help me about this,

I think there is another way to initialize the variable without having to manually put the "New" statement.

Sorry for my English

I really hope can help me. best regards

Answer (score 1):

for the statement

```
ca.Right = New CodeTypeReferenceExpression("New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application")
```

you can use

```
ca.Right = New CodeObjectCreateExpression("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application")
```